# Positioning and setting Co ordinates of any object in Xcode in xib?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, coordinates

I spend lot of time while setting the position of label, button,switch, image,cell, textfield, etc. Is there any Formula to set Co ordinates of these objects  in user desired Location in xib file.

Thanks

Comment: @Nirmal ya i know using set frame.. but how we can set frame..is there any formula to set frame co ordinates ..plz if u know let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sample Code :**

```
yourView.frame = CGRectMake(xval, yval, width, height);
//OR
[yourView setFrame:CGRectMake(xval, yval, width, height)];
```

Comment: ya i know this method but i want to know the formula how we can do movement in co ordinates

Comment: @user1609734 : What you want exactly ? What do you mean by "formula" in this case ? Explain properly.

Comment: i am not able to adjust coordinates in correct position for example..i want to make lable in right corner. how could i dentify the coordinates.. i takes me lot of time to find exact location to set the co ordinates

Comment: @user1609734 : You can drag the `UILabel` to desired position in your `.xib` file directly. If you are adding `UILabel` programatically then you have to do manual calculation (no other option) and then you can put your `UILabel` to that particular location using `CGRectMake` (as I mentioned in my Answer).

Comment: @user1609734 in your xib file x position starts from the left side and increases from left to right. and y position increases from top to bottom. so you can set x and y co-ordinates accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to set frame in .xib then you can find it in XCode as shown in figure below.

[image]

and if want to set it through coding then do following:

yourview.frame=CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);

hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Dont' forget all objects coordinate resize itself according to superview frame. If you want to change only 1 of the coordinate or size property you can use this:

```
CGRect frame = label.frame;
frame.size.height = 165.0f; //frame.size.width || frame.origin.x || frame.origin.y
cell.L_content.frame = frame;
```

otherwise if you want to do it in single line:

```
label = CGRectMake(xCoordinate, yCoordinate, width, height);
```